# Host command and ifconfig giving different ips

Tags: python, linux, networking, server, ip

I am using server(server_name.corp.com) inside a corporate company. On the server i am running a flask server to listen on 0.0.0.0:5000.

servers are not exposed to outside world but accessible via vpns.

Now when i run `host server_name.corp.com` in the box i get some ip1(`10.*.*.*`)

When i run `ifconfig` in the  box it gives me ip2(`10.*.*.*`).

Also if i run `ping server_name.corp.com` in same box i get ip2.

Also i can ssh into server with ip1 not ip2

I am able to access the flask server at ip1:5000 but not on ip2:5000.

I am not into networking so fully confused on why there are 2 different ips and why i can access ip1:5000 from browser not ip2:5000.

Also what is equivalent of host command in python ( how to get ip1 from python. I am using socktet.gethostbyname(server_name.corp.com) which gives me ip2)

Comment: Both ips start from 10.*.*.*

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you have some kind of routing configured that allows external connections to the server by hostname (or ip1), but it does not allow connection by ip2. And there is nothing unusual in this. Probably, the system administrator can advise why it is done just like this. Assuming that there are no assynchronous network routes, the following function can help to determine public ip of server:

```
import socket

def get_ip():
    try:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        sock.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
        local_address = sock.getsockname()
        sock.close()
        local_address = local_address[0]
    except OSError:
        local_address = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

    return local_address
```

Comment: still getting ip2 from it

Comment: And what about `socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())` ?

Comment: still getting ip2

Comment: @AnkitVallecha unfortunately i can't help you more. Try contact your system adminitstator for futher assistance. It's probably not programming error but server configuration

Answer (score 0):

Not quite clear about the network status by your statements, I can only tell that if you want to get ip1 by python, you could use standard lib `subprocess`, which usually be used to execute os command. (See `subprocess.Popen`)